# How to delegate calculation to child elements on react

Tags: reactjs

I have a Stateless componenet which has many stateless childs.
In order to decouple the parent calculations I wanted to delegate responsibilities to a dynamic number of childs as for example calculate their area. This way the parent can iterate over his childs and ask them for their respective area and sum for obtaining its total area.

I have read tons of docs about doing this, but they oftenly mislead me about how to implement this.

I know that refs provide a way to do this but the official docs say that if I'm using refs I might have something bad on my data flow or data model.

Is it possible to instantiate a react component ie called Shape as

```
class Canvas extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    shapesArray.push(new Shape(props));
  }
  ...
}
```

in its parent constructor method in order to hold a reference?

Does someone has the answer to this. This case is a very basic class interaction (or data modeling) problem which seems to be badly documented on React.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [..] I wanted to delegate responsibilities to the childs as for example calculate they area. This way the parent can iterate over his childs and ask them for their respective area and sum for obtaining its total area.

This doesn't fit React's conceptual model. If the parent component needs to know the value of the area, and it already has everything it needs to know in order to calculate the area, then the parent component should perform the calculation.

The only time the child component would pass back information up the component hierarchy is if it holds information that the parent component doesn't. The typical case being user input.

### UPDATE

(**TL;DR** - Beware, the following code snippets are example of how NOT to do it.)

This question has generated a lot of discussion. But I fear my explanations have not been very convincing. So let me demonstrate by way of example.

Say you have a shopping cart. The checkout page has a list of items, each with a unit price and quantity. The item's price is derived from the unit price and quantity.

The render method might look like this:

```
render() {

    return (
        <div>
            {this.props.products.map((product) => (
                <ProductItem
                    productCode={product.code}
                    unitPrice={product.unitPrice}
                    quantity={product.quantity}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

But you also want to display the sum total of items. Since each individual price is determined by the `ProductItem`, one possibility is to expose this price as a method.

```
render() {

    let total = 0;

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                {this.props.products.map((product) => {
                    let productItem = (
                        <ProductItem
                            productCode={product.code}
                            unitPrice={product.unitPrice}
                            quantity={product.quantity}
                        />
                    );
                    total += productItem.price();
                    return productItem;
                })}
            </div>
            <div>Total: ${total}</div>
        </div>
    )

}
```

If that looks clunky, well that's because React components aren't designed to be used in this way.

But it's worse than that. The parent component is now far too dependent on its child component. Say you wanted an option to hide the list of products, whilst still showing the total price. A naive solution would look like this:

```
render() {

    let total = 0;
    const showList = this.state.showList;

    return (
        <div>
            {showList ? (
                <div>
                    {this.props.products.map((product) => {
                        let productItem = (
                            <ProductItem
                                productCode={product.code}
                                unitPrice={product.unitPrice}
                                quantity={product.quantity}
                            />
                        );
                        total += productItem.price();
                        return productItem;
                    })}
                </div>
            )}
            <div>Total: ${total}</div>
        </div>
    )

}
```

Now whenever the products are hidden, the total is 0. A better solution would be:

```
render() {

    let total = 0;
    const showList = this.state.showList;

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                {this.props.products.map((product) => {
                    let productItem = (
                        <ProductItem
                            productCode={product.code}
                            unitPrice={product.unitPrice}
                            quantity={product.quantity}
                        />
                    );
                    total += productItem.price();
                    return showList ? productItem : null;
                })}
            </div>
            <div>Total: ${total}</div>
        </div>
    )

}
```

That works. But when your list is hidden, you're creating and destroying the `ProductItem` solely for the purpose of a single calculation. That's a pretty clear indication that the logic doesn't belong there.

Remember React components are views, not models.

There are several possible solutions:

- Have the parent class and the `ProductItem` class to each individually calculate the item price. However, I advise caution. If the price is simply the quantity multiplied by the unit price this might be OK. If it's more complicated than that (say involving bulk discounts, or a server request) then you don't want to be duplicating your logic.
- Calculate the item price in the parent class, and *tell* the `ProductItem` what its price is (i.e. pass it as a prop).
- Export the price calculation to a place outside the view layer. That way the parent component and the `ProductItem` component could both derive the price in the same manner from the same data.
- Finally, if you want to write your own model classes, you are free to do that as well. React is not particularly opinionated about how the application is structured outside of the view layer.

Comment: Thanks for your response David, but in general when dealing with large applications we oftenly want to delegate responsibilities to our related classes. I think that if React is delegating the rendering part to another component, why not also delegate other types of calculations?

Comment: It's about one way data flow, a core React concept. Data should only originate in the child if the parent has no need to know about it. Otherwise you have data flowing in both directions. Of course, if the area calculation required a complicated function, then that function could live outside of the component; but not in another view component.

Comment: Ok I understand that but, doesn't it sound that it breaks a bit the component concept? Taking the area calculation to another class sounds a bit redundant to me, as i would have to create a class with the view responsibility, and another with the logic responsibility... aren't webComponents meant to deal with both?

Comment: It would simply be a means of modularising your code. It would have the added benefit of making the area calculation re-usable. It doesn't have to be another class; it could simply be a function. Indeed I'd say it *should* be a (pure) function - to make clear that the component itself retains responsibility for holding the data.

Comment: Answer updated to provide examples demonstrating why the logic doesn't belong in the child component.

Comment: Thanks @DavidWalsh For your answer, let me think about it for a while before marking it as the correct answer please. There are aome things that still doesn't make total sense.

Comment: What do you think about when obtaining the data that will be sent in the props to the children, to be initialized in a class that have this methods?

Comment: Yes you could have separate model classes. For instance Backbone models + React views is a common pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you want, but why trying this ? ugly pseudocode but I think you can understand it easily.

```
ParentsComponent
  didmount: function() {
     foreach children
        calculateMyarea.call(children);
  }

  calculateMyarea : function(){ ...}
```

let me know.

Maybe add some details to your question.

Comment: Thanks francois, but how are you obtaining the reference to your children? Also, is that children reference a props object passed from a higher parent state data or an object with methods?

Comment: Oh, and in basic words I need to delegate a calculation to a dynamic number of child elements, if you think in a TodoMVC, this would be as the component that hold of the TODOs wants to know the total length of the description of each todo in the list.

Answer (score 0):

How about this.props.child, map over them and reduce to the total. For instance if you're using underscore

```
  var totalArea = _.reduce(this.props.children, function(a, b) { 
                      return a.area() + b.area(); 
                  }, 0);
```

Comment: I would advise against this. A React component is not a model class designed to expose a bunch of public methods. It's simply a view.

Comment: Tony thanks for your response but. I have a dynamic number of children (I just edited my question). And second, how did you got a reference to those children?

Comment: @DavidWalsh why not? I thought that a react component, or rather a web component, could not only expose render logic but also provide an api to interact with its data...

Comment: One way data flow is a big deal in React. Data flows down the tree, not up.

Comment: @DavidWalsh I understand that, but wouldn't that tend to couple higher level components? For example, as the more data your application start gathering, in order to manage it you will start to add more and more logic to your higher level components... I believe that decoupling is a basic Software Engineering pattern which I would be breaking by this restriction, besides, I believe (but not sure) that the react team meant with one way data flow by restricting the way in which the state of the app is communicated, which wouldn't restrict delegating calculations to child components, right?

Comment: As I said in another answer, the *logic* can live outside the view components, if necessary. But the *data* must always flow from parent to child. As for tight coupling, I believe you have it backwards: depending on the child component for essential data would too tightly couple the parent to its child.